# Tensorflow Contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am training my own model using Python on Windows 10 with TensorFlow 2.0 and Python 3.6, Anaconda 3. When I run the commands:

```
python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets.config
```

to train my images, it shows that The Tensorflow Contrib module will not be included in TensorFlow 2.0. What should I do with TensorFlow now? Do I need to upgrade or downgrade TensorFlow? Which Anaconda Promt commands should I run?

Comment: Right now only TF 2.0 alpha is available, you shouldn't be using it to run existing code as it breaks API.

Comment: Tensorflow 2.0 is now officially available. Please check https://www.tensorflow.org/

Answer (score 0):

`tf.contrib.*` will indeed disappear from tensorflow, and will not even make it to the `tf.compat*` namespace.

It is one of the breaking change in TF 2.0. There are many, many others, as it is not only a major revision of TF but a complete change of mindset IMHO. Generally speaking, you cannot really expect a TF 1.x script to run smoothly in TF 2.0, even after a run of their automatic conversion script. You *will* need to rewrite your code, and before that, rethink your way of working with TF, especially if you were ignoring the Keras API.

Answer (score 0):

In the Anaconda environment, execute:

```
conda install tensorflow=1.15
```

or

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu=1.15
```

But the warning will appear, It is the last stable version of Tensorflow 1.